# How do you configure nlog to change the file target path based on the computers architecture (32/64 bit).

Tags: nlog

Example on 32 bit OS the file target path would be c:\temp\32\ and on a 64bit c:\temp\64

Answer (score 1):

You can use a layout renderer in the filenname.

You can use:

- The [Environment layout renderer](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Environment-layout-renderer) with `PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE` variable which is AMD64 or X86 (or IA64, see [superuser](https://superuser.com/a/305902/285552)):

  Usage:  `${environment:PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE}`

  Example:

  ```xml
  <target 
     xsi:type="File"
     name="file1" 
     fileName="c:\temp\${when:when='${environment:PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE}'='X86':inner=32:else=64}\file.log" />
  ```
- Or, use the [When layout renderer](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/When-Layout-Renderer) for you conditions.

  Example, two targets:

  ```xml
  <target 
     xsi:type="File"
     name="file_32" 
     fileName="c:\temp\32\file.log" /> 
  <target 
     xsi:type="File"
     name="file_64" 
     fileName="c:\temp\64\file.log" />
  ```

  and two rules:

  ```xml
  <rules>
      <logger name="*" writeTo="file_32">
          <filters>
              <when condition="'${environment:PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE}'!='X86'" action="Ignore" />
          </filters>
      </logger>
      <logger name="*" writeTo="file_64">
          <filters>
              <when condition="'${environment:PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE}'='X86'" action="Ignore" />
          </filters>
      </logger>
  </rules>
  ```

Comment: Could you expand on this a bit? For example, do would we put this in the `writeTo` part of the logger? Or in the `fileName` field of the target? And (outside the scope of the original question), how would we access `Environment.OSVersion.Platform`?

Comment: @dthor sure, see examples :)

Comment: Wonderful, thanks! That helps my understanding a lot. Sadly now I'm getting "invalid punctuation" errors. SO comments are not great for this type of discussion, so I've opened [#1901](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/issues/1901).

Comment: I think you need single-quotes around your inner layout renderer. At least that's how I got it to work for me.

Comment: Updated and tested it, Is64BitOperatingSystem wasn't working (see also https://github.com/NLog/NLog/issues/1902) , but PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE does!